# Bluetooth multipoint playback on M2 MacBook Pro: can't play on other devices

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, bluetooth, headphones

I have a 13" M2 MacBook Pro and an iPhone 14 pro which are both connected to my ATH-M50xBT2 Bluetooth 5.0 headphones with multi-point connectivity (I can connect to two devices at a time). The multipoint connection works as expected until I lock my Mac's screen or let it go to sleep. When that happens, my headphones are still connected to both devices, but my phone can't play sounds.

For example, when I'm on the YouTube app, the play button doesn't start the video. This usually happens when one of the devices is playing something as the headphones can't play sounds from both devices at the same time. So when the Mac goes to sleep, it looks like it is hogging the headphones for no reason, preventing my phone from playing any sound. I know that one workaround is to have the Mac disconnect from Bluetooth devices when it goes to sleep, using [this app](https://github.com/odlp/bluesnooze/) for example, but I was wondering if there's another solution that doesn't involve disconnecting from Bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! Pretty annoying. I haven't found a solution yet.

If you haven't already, installing [noTunes](https://github.com/tombonez/noTunes) might also help slightly. As I assume you'd have the same issue where pressing the Play button on your headphones launches bleeping iTunes ('Music') on the Macbook.

Thanks for sharing your partial solution/workaround. Can't believe Bluetooth is still such a pain. [This is not what Josiah Bluetooth intended!](https://xkcd.com/2055/)